# Why doesn't it make sense to measure agreement with Chi square?

Tags: chi-squared-test, agreement-statistics, cohens-kappa

Why is it more useful to calculate Cohen's Kappa instead of the Pearson Chi Square test to measure the interrater agreement? Could someone please give me an example?

Comment: Can you add a reference for what you mean by more "useful"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The (Pearson) $\chi^2$ test is a test of independence which has nothing to do with agreement. The $\chi^2$ test assigns the same $p$-value to two raters who *agree* 100% of the time as to two raters who *disagree* exactly 100% of the time. The Kappa only classifies the first scenario as high agreement.